# Constant Backend Connection Errors in AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer

I am trying to use a load balancer with AWS ECS on AWS. For some reason, the graph always looks like

[image]

This happens even when there is no request coming to the load balancer at all. I cannot find this in logs either. What do this mean and what cause it?

Comment: Have you looked at the ELB logs?  How many instances are behind the balancer?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes! I checked ELB logs in S3. There were no request except the 2-3 I made manually. There are 3 EC2 instance and ~20 docker task behind it.

Comment: Hi Varun. I am facing same issue. were you able to debug !

Comment: @Ramesh Nope unfortunately :( Try contacting AWS support. Maybe they might be able to help you

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but often not regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue some time back. It is most likely caused by the health checks you have configured on the ELB. Try changing the health check to port 22 and see if it goes away. In my case, opening up the health check port in the EC2 security groups fixed it. Hope this works for you.

Comment: That's not a fix if we are using HTTP health check & we can't change it.